# How to refer to a variable range

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I want to refer a range of data in my excel sheet that is of variable range. Means this month data have 80 rows but next month it could be of 100 rows. So i just wanted a method to refer a range for variable range. So that i can use that method in following formula:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Allocation_Updt!$J$2:$J$83*((RIGHT(Allocation_Updt!$F$2:$F$83,6)+0)=$E62))/100
```

Here 83 is the last row of the data sheet. but it can be changed next time. Setting it to 10000(Almost max limit of my data) will give me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use,

```
match(1e99, Allocation_Updt!$J:$J)
```

... to find the row number of the last number or date in a column. With the last value in J83 all of the following three range references are the same thing

```
Allocation_Updt!$J$2:$J$83
Allocation_Updt!$J$2:index(Allocation_Updt!J:J, match(1e99, Allocation_Updt!$J:$J))
index(Allocation_Updt!J:J, 2)):index(Allocation_Updt!J:J, match(1e99, Allocation_Updt!$J:$J))
```

So your [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) can be dynamically limited to exactly what is needed with,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Allocation_Updt!$J$2:index(Allocation_Updt!$J:$J, match(1e99, Allocation_Updt!$J:$J))*((RIGHT(Allocation_Updt!$F$2:index(Allocation_Updt!$F:$F, match(1e99, Allocation_Updt!$J:$J)),6)+0)=$E62))/100
```

Note that the last row number in column J is used to get the last valid entry in both column F and column J.

Given the persnickety nature of SUMPRODUCT, I might perform some tests with,

```
=sumifs(Allocation_Updt!$J:$J, Allocation_Updt!$F:$F, "*"&$E62)/100
```

That is not specifically a 'right-most 6 character match'; it is an 'ends-with-E62' match. Some testing on your own data will quickly prove whether this is a viable alternative. It is more efficient, more forgiving and you can use full column references without penalty.

Comment: I might actually convert the E62 value to text rather than the RIGHT(..., 56) to a number. SUMPRODUCT chokes easily on text that cannot be converted to a number but there really isn't any number that cannot be converted to text.

Comment: tonnes of upvotes and likes to you. Both the solutions works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the range of data to a table. It will automatically apply a name to each column. These column names can be used to refer to the data in the column, and that range of data will be dynamic going forward.

Comment: I m sorry but i cant make any changes in the data layout